# Share data on local

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I've made an application for someone, with Netbeans (java) using mySQL.
Well, when I'm about to install it in his office, but it told me that it's impossible to host database!!!!
SO I have to modify the application, but I'm not sure what to do; if you have a suggestion for me; i'll be greatful
It's a java application, which is supposed to be used by several users, who share a little database.
Thank you beforehand

Comment: Not enough information. Is the database serving several clients on different machines? Or is it only a local data-repo for a single installation on a single machine? If the latter, you could use SQLite or something that doesn't need a "hosted" DB. If you need a shared database, there is really nearly no way around a (locally) hosted DB. Do they have any reasoning behind their claim?

Comment: Yes, I should have a hosted DB. They decline hosting it beceause it's a bank, the are afraid about their things.

Comment: OMG, that would be hilarious if it wasn't so sad. Do they have their own IT dept? They should know how to set up a safe dedicated DB server visible in the local net, only. I - frankly - I don't know what to say. It's ridiculous. Can you tell a bit more about the Application? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Inventory management !!  That's all !

Comment: Would it be an option to make one station a "Master" Station with a local DB and the other Clients connecting to that one? It's dirty but hey - they ask for it. Drawback is: It would have to be "always on" ...

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok @Fildor; it's impossible to host a database, but they have a local network where they can share files ... I'm thinking about using files in network; but there'sz no dirty more than this :(

Comment: Using files you'll always deal with overwriting newer data with outdated. You'd need to implement some versioning/merging system, then with the possibility to clean up conflicts. OR you just use a SQLite DB (which you can save in a file and share on a NAS) and lock it. So any one client has exclusive write-privilege or something like that. Unfortunately all this will draw you back a lot. Hope you can charge it.

Comment: I've never done anything with SQLite, I don't know how it works; well it doesn't need a server, and it's just a file. Sio, should I put this file in network? How could I access to it from application?

Comment: There should be a JDBC driver, I think. So usage is pretty similar to that of MySQL. If you have no other options than placing a db file on a network share ... then it is the way to go. Other non-hosted dbs might work also. Java DB for example.

Comment: [SQLite JDBC](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) , [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is reliant on a database to work properly I would maybe ask them if remote hosting a database is an option they can consider if "in-house" database is off the table. If your application however is not reliant on a database you might want to look into serialization where you can save it on a file instead, check out http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm. However it is hard to answer because you dont really describe what your application does.

Comment: If they are afraid of a locally hosted DB, I doubt they will be agreeing to use a remotely hosted DB ...

Comment: I guess you are right, the whole thing sounds pretty weird to me.

Comment: I totally agree. Personally I would have declined the job if the customer IT dept showed so much lack of knowledge.